# What is the algorithm of Skeleton

Tags: matlab, binary, morphological-analysis

This function **bwmorph**(Img,'**skel**',**Inf**) return the skeleton of a binary image.

What I'm looking for is the algorithm used by this function to do it manualy ?

Comment: Have you tried `edit bwmorph`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the actual code within a function in MATLAB, you can try using the [TYPE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/type.html) command:

```
type bwmorph       %# Command form
type('bwmorph.m')  %# Function form
```

Keep in mind, this will not work on all MATLAB functions. You may get a message that says the function is a built-in function, in which case the code will not be displayed. You can also try opening the file in the MATLAB Editor using the [EDIT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/edit.html) command:

```
edit bwmorph.m     %# Command form
edit('bwmorph.m')  %# Function form
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/bwmorph.html) gives an overview of the algorithm (scroll down a ways).

Comment: I'm looking for the matlab code which do the algorithm, not the mathematical algorithm.